# List the OpenStack hypervisor a host is running on using nova client

Tags: openstack

What is the fastest way to print a a host list that includes the hypervisor location from OpenStack?

The client API seems to force you to query every hypervisor individually, however this takes multiple minutes to run.

Comment: Can you access your controller node via ssh?

You can use the openstack hypervisor show or openstack hypervisor list command..

Answer (score 0):

There are commands to get the `hypervisor` related information:

```
openstack hypervisor list
openstack hypervisor show
```

**https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/pike/cli/command-objects/hypervisor.html#hypervisor-list

Comment: @cmcginty: These commands will help you to get hypervisor information. Is this what you are expecting ?